# What is a song played at the end of a movie called?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

At the end of some movies, there is a song to be played. Is there any word to call these songs?

As an example "My Heart Will Go On" from Celine Dion at the of Titanic.

Comment: I'd call it the [playout song](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22playout+song%22+movie+film&oq=%22playout+song%22+movie+film&gs_l=hp.3..33i21.4057.7766.5.8046.12.12.0.0.0.0.84.796.12.12.0...0.0...1c.r5kA2_KmWDg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=6dd2acfce60f574c&biw=1466&bih=886)

Comment: -1 Please show your research effort.

Comment: Let's be clear.  Do you mean a song that plays at the end of the actual movie, and not a song that plays during the closing titles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the industry phrase, seen on CD covers and whatnot, is **Ending Credits Theme** or **Closing Titles Theme**.

Comment: Can you cite examples? "We answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise."

Answer (score 4):

I was told that "Outro song" is sometimes used. [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/outro) has this entry for "outro":

> **outro** NOUN (plural **outros**) *informal* The concluding section of a piece of music or a radio or television program: 'the intros, outros, and bridges of various segments'

This definition could easily be extended to apply to music played at the end of a movie.

Comment: I was surprised that "outro" is in my dictionary.  Why not look in yours?

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide explanation and context. A good answer is complete and explains why it is right, ideally with citations. Answers that lack support may be removed.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good answer, see [answer].

Comment: Hi, henry, your original response had the makings of a good answer (because the term you identify **is** used in situations similar to the one that the questioner asks about), but it offered no definition and no reliable third-party sourcing for the suggested word. I revised it to include a definition from a reputable dictionary (Oxford Dictionaries online), suitably formatted, with a link to the relevant webpage, and a followup comment on why the suggestion may be a good one. You'll get a more positive response to the answers you post at this site if you include similar information in them.

Answer (score 3):

"[Exit Music (For a Film)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_Music_%28For_a_Film%29)" is the title of a song by [Radiohead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiohead) that was written for the closing credits of the 1996 film *William Shakespeare's Romeo and Juliet.* In turn, *Exit Music* was adopted by Ian Rankin as the title of his last book in the [Inspector Rebus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspector_Rebus) series.

So while I'd probably go with @ghoppe's answer for the official industry phrase, the (in my opinion) quite elegant "exit music" does have some cultural currency as well as being descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays:
I am producing and composing since over 25 years.  In the editing cutting phase, we call it outro. For puplishing reasons it's called credit-theme or closing theme.